# how include iad without changing display size

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I am using iAd and test it in my Spritekit game. So I have

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

in my ViewController.m; when I run my game in the simulator, the ad will show but everytime it shows, look like it "push" the location of the screen and make the game I am playing effect. Is there any way to make it show but not changing the screen location ? Can it just display as it overwrite (on top) of the current screen? Thank you.

Comment: btw, canDisplayBannerAds is only a testing call not an actual call to show ADs outside of sandbox.

Comment: why they need a testing call and actual call ? How do I call it for real ?